# Can I have (some) of iOS launch images in jpeg, not png in xcode5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, jpeg, splash-screen

We have an app with (unfortunately) particular launch images that are like 7 Megabytes more in PNG in respect to JPEG. With Xcode 4.6 it was possible to have Default***.jpg and it work well. 
Today I updated to Xcode5 and after submission binary is rejected with note "must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier... Launch images must be PNG files...".

Ok, so I put this single image for iphone5 in PNG but others remain in jpeg. It seems ok, but launch image is not shown anymore on other devices (so, only png image is working).

So, is it now (xcode5) not possible at all to use jpeg launch images, and is it forbidden explicitly by Apple, not just "png recommended"? Or I am missing some way to put obligatory PNG for iphone5 and keep JPEG for iPad?

Comment: Erm, 7MB PNG? Are you sure you've got the right image size?

Comment: The programming guide does say "All launch images must be PNG files and you should avoid using interlaced PNGs."

Comment: Yes, a PNG for iPad retina can become quite large (and if there is also landscape version, it gets worse...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what the doc's say about the format of the launch image:

> Every app must provide at least one launch image. This image is
>   typically in a file named Default.png that displays your app’s initial
>   screen in a portrait orientation. However, you can also provide other
>   launch images to be used under different launch conditions. All launch
>   images must be PNG files and you should avoid using interlaced PNGs.
>   The name of each launch image conveys its purpose and how it is used.
>   It is recommended that you use the following format for launch image
>   filenames

so no, you can not have the launch image in any other format it also says that the name should be Default.png. here is the link to the doc's related to the subject:

[Link to Doc's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Comment: Thanks, this document is clear enough! I can only note that it seems that now "Default-568h@2x***" is also obligatory for iphone/ipod5!

Comment: Obsolete quote. Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html

Answer (score 2):

Always optimize your images, take a look of [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/) and [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about image optimization, but did not have a reliable tool at hand.